# 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N'' in Python

Tags: python

I created a function to receive odd digits from a 7 digit code and then add them to a list named 'oddDigitList', but for some reason I get a run-time error when I run the code.

```
# A function used to add odd digits from a variable to the 'oddDigitList' list, which will be used to calculate the 8th digit of the GTIN-8 code
def formOddDigitList(variable):
    # The 'for' loop gets values from digit #1 to digit #7 in twos
    variable = str(variable)
    for i in range(0,8,2):
        variable[i]
        # The digits in the 'variable' argument are added to the 'oddDigitList' list
        # The digits are converted into integers so that they can be used to calculate the 8th digit of the GTIN-8 product code)
        oddDigitList.append(int(variable[i]))
    return variable
```

And here is the error message I got:

```
oddDigitList.append(int(variable[i]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N'
```

Can someone please explain why my code is wrong and provide a a correct version of my function.

Comment: look at the content of `variable`. As the error suggests, there is an `N` in it.

Comment: Also, learn more about creating [MCVE]. In your case, to reproduce an error we clearly need both function body **and** function arguments when error occurs.

Comment: 'variable' is 7-digit integer

Comment: Can you provide the parameters values for which the funtion fails?

Comment: In my scenario, `variable` is equal to `1234567`

Comment: 'variable[i]' after the for loop is a dummy sentence.
you can also change the for by a list by comprehension like that:
odd_digits = [int(i) for i in variable[::2]].
Also try to follow PEP8 standars in your code (i.e.: function and variable names)

Comment: I tried what you wrote and adapted it a little to my needs: `oddDigitList = [int(i) for i in variable[0,8,2]]` but then I got this error message: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @MetzLush Your selectors in _variable_ are wrong. If you want to select from 0 to 8 by steps of 2 is: variable[0:8:2]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for trying incredibly hard to answer my question and I do realise that I did need to add more to my function so that you guys knew in which the context of the function was for. Here is my teacher's solution, which completely fixes the problem that occurred:

```
oddDigitList = []

# A function used to add odd digits from a variable to the 'oddDigitList' list, which will be used to calculate the 8th digit of the GTIN-8 code
def formOddDigitList(variable):
    # The 'for' loop gets values from digit #1 to digit #7 in twos
    for i in range(0,8,2):
        # The digits in the 'variable' argument are added to the 'oddDigitList' list
        # The digits are converted into integers so that they can be used to calculate the 8th digit of the GTIN-8 product code)
        oddDigitList.append(int(variable[i]))
    return variable

# A function used as an input to assign boundaries/extremes to variables as well as enforcing 'try' and 'except' loops so that the user cannot crash the program by inputting a random number

def assignBoundariesToInput(number, text):
    while True:
        try:
            variable = input(text)
        if len(variable) != number:
            raise ValueError
    # This statement keeps looping until the user inputs the suitable data type
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input a/an", number, "digit number")
    else:
        break
    return variable

gtin7OrGtin8 = str(input("Would you the like program to:\n\n a) Calculate the GTIN-8 product code from a seven digit number\n b) Check the validity of an eight digit GTIN-8 code\n c) Exit\n\nPlease enter your designated letter: ")).lower()

if gtin7OrGtin8 == "a":
    gtinput7 = assignBoundariesToInput(7, "Enter the 7-digit code: ")
    formOddDigitList(gtinput7)
    print(oddDigitList)

else:
    pass
```

As I said before, I am deeply sorry for not adding the additional detail to help you guys resolve the bug. In the future I will ensure to always add context into the problem to help the community answer any problems that occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you want:

```
def formOddDigitList(number):
    """
        A function used to add odd digits from a variable to the 'oddDigitList' list,
        which will be used to calculate the 8th digit of the GTIN-8 code
    """

    oddDigitList = []

    string = str(number)

    # get values for only the odd digits from digit #1 to digit #7

    for i in range(0, 7, 2):
        # The digits in the 'string' variable are added to the 'oddDigitList' list
        # The digits are converted into integers so that they can be used to calculate the product code
        oddDigitList.append(int(string[i]))

    return oddDigitList


print(formOddDigitList(9638507))
```

RETURNS/PRINTS:

```
[9, 3, 5, 7]
```

For GTIN-8, I assume you want the odd digits to multiply them by a constant and add them to the even digits.  All of which could be done by a single function.